# FIles not appearing on mapped drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2012-r2, mapped-drive

When I access a mapped drive located on one of our servers from my client laptop the drive doesn't appear to refresh.

In other words, if one of my colleagues updates a file or adds a new file, it doesn't appear when I access the mapped drive. However all my other colleagues are able to see and access the file. When I create new files/update existing files, it appears that my colleagues cannot see the file either.

When I log on to the server I can see the updates/new files that my colleagues have added but not the ones that I have.

My operating system is windows 7 and the server is on Windows Server 2012R2

Comment: Sort of sounds like it could be an issue with Offline Files not syncing.  Do you know if you use Offline Files?

Comment: I was using offline files but I've since switched that off and the problem has still persisted